# How to show another page light box using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to load popup modals from another page using jquery. I used anchor tag to open the popup modals. Also used jQuery's load() function.The popup boxes looping with each others. But my code fail to load the modals. what I need to do. Anyone please help me. Thanks in advance. below is the code I used.

In index.html

```
<a href="#openModal1" id="openModalBtn">open modal1</a>
<a href="#openModal2" id="openModalBtn">open modal2</a>
<a href="#openModal3" id="openModalBtn">open modal3</a>

<div id="content"></div>

$(function(){
    $("#openModalBtn").on("click", function(){
        $("content").load("modal.html#openModal3");  
    });

});
```

In modal.html

```
<div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
       <input class="getAssignment2" type="button" value="Previous" id="prev">
        <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Next" id="next">
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
   <h2>Modal Box 1</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog">
    <div>   
    <input class="getAssignment2" type="button" value="Previous" id="prev">
        <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Next" id="next">
   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
   <h2>Modal Box 2</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="openModal3" class="modalDialog">
    <div>   
     <input class="getAssignment2" type="button" value="Previous" id="prev">
        <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Next" id="next">
   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
   <h2>Modal Box 3</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".getAssignment2").click(function() {
   var pNode = $(this).closest(".modalDialog"),
       id = pNode.prev(".modalDialog").attr("id") ||
         $('.modalDialog').last().attr("id");;
   window.location.href = "#" + id;
 });
 $(".getAssignment").click(function() {
   var pNode = $(this).closest(".modalDialog"),
       id = pNode.next(".modalDialog").attr("id") ||
         $('.modalDialog').first().attr("id");
   window.location.href = "#" + id;
 });
});
```

styles.css

```
        .modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
    background: #00d9ff;
}
.getAssignment{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: So what does happen? Any errors? Is page reloading? Have you inspected requests in browser dev tools network?  Just telling us *"it's not working"* is almost meaningless without any troubleshooting details

Comment: It is not display an error on  browser dev tools network.

Comment: So the request has a 200 status and is returning the expected html in response body?

Comment: `<a href="#openModal1" id="openModalBtn">open modal1</a>
<a href="#openModal2" id="openModalBtn">open modal2</a>
<a href="#openModal3" id="openModalBtn">open modal3</a>`

You can't set same ID more than 1.. ID must be unique..